# Create an entity from an existing database, but tables are missing

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have created my database in Symfony with

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity
```

I have created my repository too.
But when I look at the entity directory, one important table is missing.

In this table there is a lot of important information for my website, but I can't access it, because the entity does not exist.

I have no error with the import and not error in the database (I think).

Table on HeidiSQL:

[image: Table on HeidiSQL]

The entity on the Symfony web site:

[image: Entity in symfony webSite]

I have not demande_etape.
Why and how i can make this table in entity ?

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I'm not very comfortable in English

Answer (score 0):

I don't no why but if symfony not detect ID key, he can't import the table and make joins in table on both side.
So I created my entity myself and i put id_Demande field and id_Etape field in ID.
It's wotking !